# htaccess category structure

Tags: .htaccess, categories

im looking to build a category structure and rewrite the url.

the category levels vary from 1 to infinite but the rewrites i'm using are particular inefficient and are causing problems. The rules below allow me to build up 3 categories levels.

```
RewriteRule ^c/([^.]+)-([^.]+)-([^.]+)-([^.]+)-([^.]+)-([^.]+)$ category.php?cat1=$1&id1=$2&cat2=$3&id2=$4&cat=$5&id=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([^.]+)-([^.]+)-([^.]+)-([^.]+)$ category.php?cat1=$1&id1=$2&cat=$3&id=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^c/([^.]+)-([^.]+)$ category.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Im looking to find out way to reduce the above to one line which cope with additional categories levels on the fly. cat1=$1&id1=$2&cat2=$3 etc aren't used on the category.php page only 'cat=$1&id=$2' is important.

There must be a way to insert something here [**RULE**] which can monitor the current uri.

```
RewriteRule ^c/[***RULE***]([^.]+)-([^.]+)$ category.php?[***RULE***]cat=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^c/([^.]+)-([^.]+)(?:-([^.]+)-([^.]+))?(?:-([^.]+)-([^.]+))?$ category.php?cat1=$1&id1=$2&cat2=$3&id2=$4&cat=$5&id=$6 [L]
```

Comment: thanks that sort of works but i need to take into consideration category.php?cat1=$1&id1=$2&cat2=$3&id2=$4&cat=$5&id=$6 is there a way of using %{QUERY_STRING} category.php?%{QUERY_STRING}cat=$5&id=$6 im using the query string to build up breadcrumbs